# The problem with Number of extension points

Tags: algorithms

I thought of a problem like this. In the shortest path algorithm,
if $dist(x,i) + dist(i,y)<dist(x,y)$
(x , i , y all represent the vertices of the graph), you can Update dist(x,y). I want to know how many times dist(x,y) should be checked according to this update method.

---

This can be abstracted into another question:

Given n points in a two-dimensional plane:
$(x1,y1) , (x2,y2) , (x3,y3) ... (xn,yn)$.

If two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$  meet the following conditions: $b = c$ , a new point $ (a,d) $ can be generated

Then find out how many points can be expanded at most.

---

> Input:    coordinates of n points

> (x1,y1) ,  (x2,y2) , ... (xn,yn)

> Output:     how many points can be expanded at most

> number of points

---

I can only think of the enumeration method. Each time I enumerate all the point pairs to determine whether the requirements are met, and repeat this process until all points fail to generate new points.

---

Please give a general solution.
Thank you so much for any ideas.

Comment: please, report where did you find this problem, and also some of your try. There is a contest right now, and we got to be sure this problem doesn't come from it

Comment: The question has been modified   : )